# Icon to de right side of the view React-native

Tags: react-native, layout, alignment

im trying to keep my icon in the right side of View component. But im failed.

```
<StyledView>
        <StyledListItem {...props}>
            {value}
            <Icon name="add" size={24} style={{ right: 0 }} />
        </StyledListItem>
        <StyledLine></StyledLine>
    </StyledView>
```

styles components:

```
    import styled from 'styled-components/native';
    import colors from "../../../styles/colors";
    import { styledfont } from "../../../styles/fonts";

    export const StyledList = styled.TextInput`
     height: 40px;
     border: 1px solid gray;
     width: 100%;
     padding: 0 10px;
     `;

    export const StyledListItem = styled.Text`
    ${styledfont.h4}
     color: ${colors.blue.primary};
     width: 72%;
     margin-bottom: 15px;
     margin-top: 13px;
      margin-left:28px;
     flex-direction: row;
      `;

               export const StyledView = styled.View`
   width: 100%;
   height: 68px;
  `;

   export const StyledLine = styled.View`
    width: 100%;
     height: 1px;
     background-color: ${colors.blue.primaryopc20};
     `;

    export const StyledContainer = styled.View`
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    flex: 1;
    `;
```

[image: that's my result:]

I try a lot of things, someone can help me? I think that I should use something like flex row, but I do not know how to apply that.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me like you are using the positioning. I don't expect the `{right: 0}` to work without positioning. Try making the StyledListItem have a relative position and then position the Icon absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

You can add positioning to your components. In this case, I'd try:

```
<StyledView>
            <StyledListItem style={{position: 'relative'}} {...props}>
               {value}
                    <Icon name="add" size={24} style={{ position: 'absolute', right: 0 }} />
            </StyledListItem>
            <StyledLine></StyledLine>
</StyledView>
```

You can even leave out the `relative` positioning on the parent since in react native everything is positioned `relative` by default

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap icon in view and use marginLeft:'auto' property as:-

````
```
        <StyledView>
            <StyledListItem {...props}>
               {value}
               <View style={{marginLeft:'auto'}}>
                    <Icon name="add" size={24} style={{ right: 0 }} />
               </View>
            </StyledListItem>
            <StyledLine></StyledLine>
        </StyledView>
```
````